# Input fields with blur() and focus()

Tags: jquery, input, contact-form

I'm building a custom contact form. All my input fields have a mouseenter/mouseleave and focus/blur animations (background-color). My problem stands with the blur() and focus().
Here's the code for the Name field:

```
  $('#userName').on('mouseenter', function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
     $('#userName').animate({'background-color':'#FECC00'}, 200);
    }
  });

  $('#userName').on('mouseleave', function(){
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
      $(this).stop(true).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 200);
    }
  });

  $('#userName').focus(function(){
    $(this).animate({'background-color':'#B0CB1F'}, 200);

  });

  $('#userName').blur(function(){
    $(this).animate({'background-color':'#ffffff'}, 200);
    if($.trim($(this).val()) == ""){
      nameInvalidation();
    }
    else{
      nameValidation();
    }
  });
```

The nameInvalidation() and nameInvalidation() are some animated checkmarks:

- nameInvalidation(): grayed out checkmark - input field needs to be filled - this is the default for all input fields;
- nameValidation(): green checkmark - field data is ready to be sent;

When I enter the input field and do nothing the nameInvalidation() runs; when I input something the nameValidation() runs - so I know if the field is ready or not.
The problem is this:

- if I enter the input filed and it's empty
- if if I leave it empty
- if I write something but delete it before leaving the input field

... than the nameInvalidation() animations is NOT suppose to run, because it's already as default.

The same thing for when the field as some data and I get in it, change or just leave... the green checkmark runs again.

I tried using keyup() and it worked at some extent but it runs the checkmark animation at each keystroke - I only want it when I leave the field.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjU4k/).

Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a variable which hold current status of called method

check [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RjU4k/1/)

```
    var currentValidationMethodMane;
    function nameValidation(){
        if(currentValidationMethodMane == "nameValidation"){
            return;
        }
        currentValidationMethodMane = "nameValidation";
   .........

function nameInvalidation(){
        if(currentValidationMethodMane == "nameInvalidation"){
        return;
    }
    currentValidationMethodMane = "nameInvalidation";

.....
```

Comment: Simple and effective - works great! There's just one little thing: the *first time* we click inside the input field and leave, it animates the gray checkmark. After that, everything works flawlessly. Can you do something about it?